# undefined method `pushViewController' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ios, rubymotion, pushviewcontroller

I built a rubymotion app that is currently pending review by Apple. I have crittercism hooked to my app and noticed that during the review process, an error occurred. However, I am not able to replicate this error on my iPhone 4S.

The error occurred on: iPad Air using 7.1.2 and on Wifi (not on cellular data).

The error is: `undefined method pushViewController for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

and it seems to occur in this part of my code:

```
  def locationManager(manager, didUpdateToLocation:newLocation, fromLocation:oldLocation)
    @my_location_manager.stopUpdatingLocation
    #error occurs on the line below
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(MyController.alloc.initWithData(item, newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude), animated:true)
  end
```

The entire class looks something like this:

```
class SomeController < UITableViewController
   def locationManager(manager, didUpdateToLocation:newLocation, fromLocation:oldLocation)
      @my_location_manager.stopUpdatingLocation
      #error occurs on the line below
      self.navigationController.pushViewController(MyController.alloc.initWithData(item, newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude), animated:true)
   end

  def tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath)
      initAFNetworkingClient
      @name = self.data[indexPath.row][:name]  
      if @name == "FooBar"

        if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled)
          @my_location_manager = CLLocationManager.alloc.init
          @my_location_manager.delegate = self

          @my_location_manager.purpose = "To provide functionality based on user's current location"
          @my_location_manager.startUpdatingLocation
        else
          p "Location services are not enabled."
        end
      elsif @name == "Bar"
        self.navigationController.pushViewController(OtherController.alloc.init, animated: true)
      end    
end
```

Can someone shed some light as to why my app would be getting this error? Or how can I replicate the issue on my device? or if I'm clearly doing something wrong here.

Comment: Run with the Release scheme and see if you can get the error.

Comment: Did you tried `presentViewController` instead of `pushViewController` ?

Comment: @duci9y what is "Release scheme"?

Comment: Google it. When you test your app on a device you do it using the Debug scheme, when someone downloads it from the App Store and runs it, it runs under the Release scheme.

Comment: Your navigationController is ``nil`` at that point

Comment: You probably don't have any navigation controller.